# How can I check a checkbox on the popup window? Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, netbeans-7

When a popup window open how can I handle on this window?

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        MenuUtil.doClickMenu(selenium, driver, "Access 2G", "Cảnh báo", "Giám sát cảnh báo BTS");
        ControlBase.waitForLoadOk(5);
        CheckBoxUtil.doCheckByXpath(selenium, "//*[@id='listRow1']/tbody/tr[1]/td[18]/input");
        ControlBase.waitForLoadOk(5);
        ButtonUtil.doClickByLabel(driver, "Cập nhật");
        ControlBase.waitForLoadOk(5);
        CheckBoxUtil.doCheckByXpath(selenium, "//*[@id='txtName']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally I use the Selenium IDE. Here you can 'click & record', which allows you to then get the XPath of the JS pop-up alert box.

I would suggest you first check for the alert box showing up with something such as this:

```
if (selenium.isAlertPresent()){

     System.out.println(selenium.getAlert()); //show alert text message
     selenium.click("id=alertbox_ok_btn"); //click OK on alert box         
}
```

Download Selenium IDE from here: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Also, refer to Selenium's documentation for Java here: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code written in JAVA

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("Your application URL");

String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
//click on the link/box/whatever to open the pop up
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();

Set <String> popupWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for(String popup : popupWindows){
driver.switchTo().window(popup);
    //you can use getTitle/getCurrentUrl to match with title/url of the pop up
if(driver.getTitle().equals("actual title on the pop up")){
            break;
        }
    }

//Write a code to check a checkbox
//Close the pop up
driver.close();
//Come back to the parent window
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
//Code if you want to test/do something else
driver.close();
```